# Merge pageLoadTime with other dimensions and metrics

Tags: google-analytics

I have the below dimensions and metrics of which extracted the data from analyticsreporting v4 object of Google Analytics.

```
Table A:
Dimensions: dateHour, campaign, keyword, sourceMedium, browser, deviceCategory, pagePath, pageTitle
Metrics: totalEvents, uniqueEvents, goal8Completions, goal9Completions, goal10Completions, sessions, bounces, users, newUsers, pageviews
```

Now my objective was to include **pageLoadTime** with the above metrics but as we know it does not go with some of the metrics like totalEvents, etc.

So keeping all the dimensions as above, i then extracted only pageLoadTime metrics and when I did left join with the **Table A** data, most of the values of the column was empty.

Query: Is there any other way to join pageLoadTime with the above list of Metrics? or is it even possible?

Comment: @DaImTo I am sorry but, with due respect, this question is not related to coding as much as it is to the logic behind it.

Comment: If its not programming related then please dont use the -api tags.  I think you would be better off posting it https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as stack is mostly for coding issues if you want to know information about how Google analytics application works then i suggest you try there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oageLoadTime is by default sampled. This would explain why a lot of it is empty. You will only have that metric for dimensions where the load time is captured.

Comment: Thanks @XTOTHEL . Would it be possible to impute the empty values keeping those dimensions common which affect it (pageLoadTime)?